# angular dynamic locale not working on all browser

Tags: angularjs, angular-i18n

I have problem with angular-translate and angular-dynamic-locale.
Locale and translate works in chrome, but in another browser not working.I work on localhost, but when i put on server, in all browser translate work but locale don't. Can someone help. here is code

```
.config(function(tmhDynamicLocaleProvider) {
tmhDynamicLocaleProvider.localeLocationPattern('bower_components/angular-i18n/angular-locale_{{locale}}.js');

});
```

added this in ctrl

```
$rootScope.availableLocales = {
        'en': 'English',
        'hr': 'Hrvatski'};
    $rootScope.model = {selectedLocale: 'en'};
    $rootScope.$locale = $locale;
    $rootScope.changeLocale = tmhDynamicLocale.set;
```

in html i use this

```
<li><a ng-model="model.selectedLocale" ng-click="changeLanguage('hr'); changeLocale('hr')" translate="BUTTON_LANG_CRO"></a></li>
                <li><a ng-model="model.selectedLocale" ng-click="changeLanguage('en'); changeLocale('en')" translate="BUTTON_LANG_EN"></a></li>
```

Translate switch always work

Comment: please modify your question, some codes are missing from first block.

Comment: Sry,  which block?  Sry for my english